# Multi-value queryString in Wiremock

Tags: uri, stubbing, wiremock

in older versions of Wiremock we could append te queryString to the matching url like this:

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/rest/customer/find?custId=1&custId=2")) //
                .willReturn(aResponse()) //
```

but now that we upgraded to recent versions we are bound to use withQueryParam method of the mapping builder - wiremock doesn't understand appended params anymore. But how do we achieve such behavior? I couldn't figure out how to inject the multi-value parameter in the stub.

```
Integer[] custIds = {1, 2};
wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/rest/customer/find")) //
                .withQueryParam("userIds", equalTo(custIds.toString())) //
                .willReturn(aResponse()) //
```

This doesn't work when we call the url with path "/rest/customer/find?custId=1&custId=2" from restTemplate.

Comment: WireMock still understands appended params if you use `urlEqualTo`. This hasn't changed.

Comment: @Tom  it doesn't seem to work though. See answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to append the query params in the url results in this error:

```
2016-12-07 10:31:49.205 ERROR 1835 --- [qtp846274760-33] WireMock                                 SFID= : Request was not matched:
{
  "url" : "/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8",
  "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:8889/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8",
  "method" : "GET",
  "clientIp" : "127.0.0.1",
  "headers" : {
    "User-Agent" : "Java/1.8.0_91",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "Host" : "localhost:8889",
    "Accept" : "application/json, application/*+json"
  },
  "cookies" : { },
  "browserProxyRequest" : false,
  "loggedDate" : 1481113909179,
  "bodyAsBase64" : "",
  "body" : "",
  "loggedDateString" : "2016-12-07T12:31:49Z"
}
Closest match:
{
  "url" : "http://localhost:8889/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8",
  "method" : "GET"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8"))
```

or

```
stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/rest/user/list"))
                .withQueryParam("userIds", equalTo("5"))
                .withQueryParam("userIds", equalTo("6"))
                .withQueryParam("userIds", equalTo("7"))
                .withQueryParam("userIds", equalTo("8"))
```

Comment: The `stubFor` approach won't work! check the generated request: `{
  "urlPath" : "/rest/user/list",
  "method" : "GET",
  "queryParameters" : {
    "userIds" : {
      "equalTo" : "8"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: With the `"/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8"` approach the request is: `{
    "urlPath" : "/rest/user/list?userIds=5&userIds=6&userIds=7&userIds=8",
    "method" : "GET"
  }` but one has to be careful about parameters encoding on consumer side! not great. This is a **feature request** at WireMock: https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/398.

Comment: The approach does not work as the "userIds" is overwritten with the last value always. Depending on the example it will always be like
`Query: userIds= 8 
userIds: 8`